# 2 Column responsive layout with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, responsive

How do i create a 2 column grid in Bootstrap 4 that is responsive but the column widths are not fixed.
For example: I will have an image in the LEFT column of some width and I want the RIGHT column to flex to the remaining width of the parent DIV.

```
<div class="tut_wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
         <div class="tut_leftbox"><img class="img-fluid" src="tutorials/anamorphic_drawing1.jpg"></div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
         <div class="tut_rightbox">
              <h3>Introduction</h3>
              some text
         </div>
     </div>    
     </div>    
     </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a div use up the space left, you just need to add the class `col` to that div. It will automatically assign all the space left to it. Under mobile view (when the left div occupies the whole row), the div will automatically become 100% wide.

```css
div {
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      ex: col-4
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      this will take up all the space left
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to have your left div 100% fit with the image, you could do `col-xs-auto` to the left div and `col` to the right div.

```css
div {
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-xs-auto">
      Fixed width image here
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Other content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Details of Bootstrap 4 grid system could be found [HERE](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Comment: Thank you Gabriel - but what if the image in the left column is larger than col-4 as you specified it? I do not want the image to shrink. I also dont want to define the column as col-6 and have open space if the image is smaller than col-6....hope that makes sense

Comment: @Henk then use my second example's code, using `col-xs-auto`